# What is the Home Office reference number?

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes

I am filling a tax credit form, and it asks for my Home Office reference number. What is the Home Office reference number, and where do I find it? I have a Tier 2 UK Visa.

Comment: Closing as being an expat does not make this question unique - ie it's the same whether you're an expat or not.